# expand and collapse row for ng-table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to achieve an expand and collapse row for ng-table, basically what we want is if you click on row it expands with more detail. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Any help appreciated thanks

```js
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module('main', ['ngTable']).
        controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $filter, ngTableParams,$timeout) {
            var data = [
                {ticket: 1,Date: "24-3-2015", Status: "Pending" ,name: "Moroni", Agent: "cherrylabs1" , Item: "test1" , Description: "this is 1" ,age: 50},
                {ticket: 2,Date: "25-3-2015", Status: "Pending" ,name: "Tiancum",Agent: "cherrylabs2" , Item: "test2" , Description: "this is 2"  ,age: 43},
                {ticket: 3,Date: "26-3-2015", Status: "Pending" ,name: "Jacob", Agent: "cherrylabs3" , Item: "test3" , Description: "this is 3" ,age: 27},
                {ticket: 4,Date: "27-3-2015", Status: "Pending" ,name: "Nephi", Agent: "cherrylabs4" , Item: "test4" , Description: "this is 4", age: 29},
                {ticket: 5,Date: "28-3-2015", Status: "Pending" ,name: "Enos", Agent: "cherrylabs5" , Item: "test5" , Description: "this is 5" ,age: 34},
                {ticket: 6,Date: "29-3-2015", Status: "Pending" ,name: "Tiancum", Agent: "cherrylabs6" , Item: "test6" , Description: "this is 6" ,age: 43},
                {ticket: 7,Date: "30-3-2015", Status: "Pending" ,name: "Jacob", Agent: "cherrylabs7" , Item: "test7" , Description: "this is 7" ,age: 27},
                {ticket: 8,Date: "31-3-2015", Status: "Pending" ,name: "Nephi",Agent: "cherrylabs8" , Item: "test8" , Description: "this is 8" , age: 29}
              
                ];
            $scope.columns = [
                { title: 'Ticket', field: 'ticket', visible: true },
                { title: 'Date', field: 'Date', visible: true },
                { title: 'Status', field: 'Status', visible: true },
                { title: 'Customer', field: 'name', visible: true },
                { title: 'Agent', field: 'Agent', visible: true },
                { title: 'Item', field: 'Item', visible: true },
                { title: 'Description', field: 'Description', visible: true }
             
                
               
            ];
            
 
         
           $scope.$watch("filter.$", function () {
    $scope.tableParams.reload();
   });
   
            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,            // show first page
                count: 10,          // count per page
                filter: {
                    name: 'M'       // initial filter
                }
            }, {
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            var filteredData = $filter('filter')(data, $scope.filter);
            var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                                $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
                                filteredData;

            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        },
        $scope: $scope
    });
            
           
        })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.0-rc3-nonmin" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ng-table@*" data-semver="0.3.1" src="http://bazalt-cms.com/assets/ng-table/0.3.1/ng-table.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ng-table-export@0.1.0" data-semver="0.1.0" src="http://bazalt-cms.com/assets/ng-table-export/0.1.0/ng-table-export.js"></script>
    
    <link data-require="ng-table@*" data-semver="0.3.0" rel="stylesheet" href="http://bazalt-cms.com/assets/ng-table/0.3.0/ng-table.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="main" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
  
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">

   
    
   
    <p>Filter: <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="filter.$" /></p>
<br >
    <table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-show="column.visible"
                class="text-center sortable" ng-class="{
                    'sort-asc': tableParams.isSortBy(column.field, 'asc'),
                    'sort-desc': tableParams.isSortBy(column.field, 'desc')
                  }"
                ng-click="tableParams.sorting(column.field, tableParams.isSortBy(column.field, 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc')">
                {{column.title}}
                <div ng-if="!template" ng-show="!template" ng-bind="parse(column.title)" class="ng-scope ng-binding"></div>
            </th>
        </tr>
       
        
        
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data"">
            <td ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-show="column.visible" sortable="column.field" style="text-align:center;">
                {{user[column.field]}}
            </td>
         
          
         
        </tr>

       
       
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```